# postgresql trigger function to check a date of a concert

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, constraints

So I have a problem with trigger function before insert on table performance.

In table performance I have

```
id_performance(PK)
id_performer(foreign key)
id_concert(FK)
id_song(FK)
role (it can be violine, sopran, alt etc)
```

In table concert I have:

```
id(PK), 
name,
date 
id_location(FK).
```

In table performer I have:

```
id(PK), 
FirstName 
LastName.
```

I need to check before insert on table performance, the date of the concert in table concert because one performer can only perform one concert per day, while concert can have many performers. So i need trigger function that wouldn't allow to add to the performance perfomer which already have a concert that day.

Here is a image of E-R diagram: http://prntscr.com/e4cf92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following trigger function follows the logic as specified. It can be futher optimized (you actually don't need to queries), but I think this ways it's easier to understand:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_only_one_concert_per_day() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE
    -- These are two variables used later on
    _present_concert_date    date ;
    _concert_count_same_date integer ;
BEGIN
    -- Check the concert date, and store it in variable
    -- NOTE that our current concert id is stored in NEW.id_concert,
    --   the id_concert of the row about to be inserted.
    SELECT
        concert.date
    INTO
        _present_concert_date
    FROM
        concert
    WHERE
        concert.id = NEW.id_concert ;  

    -- Check to see how many performances has our performer booked
    -- for the day of the current concert
    -- NOTE that the current "performer" is NEW.id_performer
    SELECT
        count(*)
    INTO    
        _concert_count_same_date
    FROM
        performance
        JOIN concert ON concert.id = performance.id_concert
    WHERE
            performance.id_performer = NEW.id_performer
        AND concert.date = _present_concert_date ;

    -- If the count of concerts is > 0, complain!
    if _concert_count_same_date > 0 then
        -- This will raise an exception, and abort current transaction
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot have more than one concert per day, already % concert(s) is/are booked for %', _concert_count_same_date, _present_concert_date ;
        -- As an alternative, a RETURN null could also be possible.
    end if ;
    RETURN NEW ;  -- If no exception, go on and return the row untouched
END 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

And this is how you associate this function with an "ON BEFORE" trigger on your `performance` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_one_concert_per_day 
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON performance 
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE p.check_only_one_concert_per_day();
```

You need to check the following parts of the documentation to get the whole picture:

1. [Documentation on triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html)
2. [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)
3. [Documentation on exceptions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)
4. [PL/pgSQL language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add the `date` to the performances and use a [constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp) afterwards. The [`UNIQUE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) constraint seems the best one.

> [The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Therefor you would have to add a constraint of unicity on `id_performer AND date`. This way a performer would only be able to be matched once a day regardless of which concert he would be performing on.

Comment: This really is  the simplest way, but my teacher obviously loves trigger function and he insists that we do that with trigger function and I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Haven't seen that part of my course yet. You'll need to wait for someone else, my apologies.